# Docker with Nginx, Portainer, HHVM, and UFW

Tags: networking, docker, ufw, hhvm

I have a vps, running docker, with `nginx` and `hhvm`. So far, so good:
The images I use are the official nginx, and [brunoric/hhvm](https://hub.docker.com/r/brunoric/hhvm/)

To have it play nicely with UFW, I had to disable the use of iptables by adding:

```
{ "iptables": false }
```

in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

This seems to compromise port mapping somehow. Eq. if I try to start hhvm on any port other than 9000, I can't access it with nginx. If I try to start `portainer` on any alternative port, I can't access it. They both default to port 9000, so I cannot use them together.

How can I fix that?

Comment: What network driver are you using for each container?

Comment: The default. Bridge.